# Multiple select statements in one query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can do the following in 2 queries but want to make it simpler. Can this be combined in one query? If so how more efficient is it than doing two queries vs one?

```
query1: SELECT page_id, coupon_id from table_1 WHERE key = :key
query2: SELECT folder from table_2 WHERE page_id = table_1.page_id
```

For my final result I need to have a coupon_id from table_1, and a folder from table_2.

In query2 I need to use the page_id result from query1 to get the folder

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) (`LEFT`, `RIGHT` or `INNER` is up to your needs):

```
SELECT 
    t1.page_id, 
    t1.coupon_id,
    t2.folder
FROM
    table_1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN table_2 AS t2 ON
        t2.page_id = t1.page_id
WHERE
    t1.key = :key
```

Comment: Thanks! Works just how I wanted it to.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to `JOIN` the tables on the `page_id`:

```
SELECT t1.page_id, 
    t1.coupon_id, 
    t2.folder
from table_1 t1
inner join table_2 t2
    on t1.page_id = t2.page_id
WHERE key = :key
```

If you need help learning join syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

I used an `INNER JOIN` which will return all rows that match between the two tables.  If you want to return all rows from `table_1` 
even if it doesn't have a matching row in `table_2`, then you would use a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @SpencerTreeHouse It comes in very handy when you are trying to figure out the correct join.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  table_1.coupon_id AS coupon_id,
  table_2.folder AS folder
FROM
  table_1
  INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_2.page_id = table_1.page_id
WHERE
  table_1.key = :key
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.page_id, t1.coupon_id, t2.folder
FROM table_1 t1 LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON (t1.page_id = t2.page_id)
WHERE t1.key = :key
```

This will be faster than two queries, how much depends on your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
SELECT a.page_id, a.coupon_id, b.folder_id 
from table_1 a
join table_2 b
ON a.page_id = b.page_id
WHERE a.key = :key
group by a.page_id
;
```